# MVC3 IControllerFactory ReleaseController memory leak

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, design-patterns, dependency-injection

In our project we use MefControllerFactory, these are the codes which we set at application_start in global.asax as `ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new Project.Helper.MefControllerFactory(container));`

The problem is when we run .NET Profiler in result, it gives memory leak problem even we dispose controllers in "ReleaseController" method. The original message is *"An instance is disposed but still reachable from one or more roots. Since a disposed instance should normally no longer be used, this can indicate a memory leak. Investigate the instance to find out whether the instance is unintentionally kept alive, or if the issue can be ignored."* 
Is there any solution for this problem ?

**The second message is:** 
"Disposed instance with direct EventHandler roots
A disposed instance is directly rooted by an EventHandler, i.e., the instance is only used as the target of an EventHandler and it cannot be reached from any other root without passing through a delegate. Since a disposed instance should no longer be used and EventHandlers are a common cause of memory leaks, this issue is a strong indication of a memory leak."

```
public class MefControllerFactory : IControllerFactory
{
    private CompositionContainer _container;
    private DefaultControllerFactory defaultControllerFactory;

    public MefControllerFactory(CompositionContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
        this.defaultControllerFactory = new DefaultControllerFactory();
    }

    #region IControllerFactory Members

    public IController CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        IController controller = null;

        controller = _container.GetExportedValueOrDefault<IController>(controllerName);

        if (controller == null)
            return this.defaultControllerFactory.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);

        return controller;
    }

    public void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        IDisposable disposable = controller as IDisposable;
        if (disposable != null)
            disposable.Dispose();
    }

    #endregion


    public System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior GetControllerSessionBehavior(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        return System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Default;
    }
}
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the MEF-based Controller Factory I created for the code samples for [my book](http://affiliate.manning.com/idevaffiliate.php?id=1150_236):

```
public class MefControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly CompositionContainer container;
    private readonly Dictionary<IController, Lazy<object, object>> exports;
    private readonly object syncRoot;

    public MefControllerFactory(CompositionContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        }

        this.container = container;
        this.exports = new Dictionary<IController, Lazy<object, object>>();
        this.syncRoot = new object();
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(
        RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        var export = this.container.GetExports(
            controllerType, null, null).Single();
        var controller = (IController)export.Value;
        lock (this.syncRoot)
        {
            this.exports.Add(controller, export);
        }
        return controller;
    }

    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        lock (this.syncRoot)
        {
            var export = this.exports[controller];
            this.exports.Remove(controller);

            this.container.ReleaseExport(export);
        }
        base.ReleaseController(controller);
    }
}
```

In MEF, you can only Release object graphs by releasing the *Export* - not the exported *value*.